# Отображение части массива в зависимости от размеров экрана vue js

Tags: массивы, vue.js, nuxt.js

У меня есть массив пяти объектов. При изменении размеров экрана мне надо, чтобы массив отображался частично. Например, вместо 4 объектов происходит отображение трех, затем двух, в зависимости от размеров экрана. 
Понимаю, что в данной ситуации актуален будет метод slice. Но полная реализация подобного мне непонятна сейчас

Comment: Можете предоставить код компонента?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот набросал готовый пример https://codepen.io/dvomaks/pen/dyPexMQ

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    items: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
  },
  computed: {
    cropItems() {
      const l = Math.round(this.width / 100);
      return this.items.slice(0, l);
    }
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
    this.handleResize();
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
  },
  methods: {
    handleResize() {
      this.width = window.innerWidth;
      this.height = window.innerHeight;
    }
  }
});
```

Для проверки нужно уменьшить окно браузера по ширине. Надеюсь я правильно понял суть задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то один из вариантов реализации, с использованием [Bootstrap-Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/)

```
<b-container>
  <b-row>
    <b-col v-for="item in items" sm="4">{{ item }}</b-col>
  </b-row>
</b-container>
```

```
    ...
    data() {
      return {
        items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
      }
    }
    ...
```

Вот [ссылка](https://codepen.io/pen?&editable=true&editors=101) на рабочий пример.